# touch optimized horizontal accordion

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, accordion, sencha-touch

I´m working on an website, which will be presented only on iPad, thats why it must be very user friendly and touch optimized.

I need an horizontal accordion eg like this one http://www.portalzine.de/Horizontal_Accordion_Plugin_2/index.html, but I want that the panels could be changed by swiping with a finger.

I have also looked at sencha touch, there are few examples of carrousels, but that is not what i want - i want the borders (handles of the panels) to remain visible (just like in the accordion). I would prefer Sencha, because of it uses hardware acceleration, so the animations are smooth, but I have no skills in it, only in jQuery.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve it? Is there any horizontal accordion plugin for Sencha? Or any "touch optimized" accordion for jQuery/jQuery mobile?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In your example link, what have you tried?

Comment: I only tried to use it, but because of that I have a little bit different layout - with no success - I need the handle to be over the left part of the "panel". But thats not a problem, I think I can manage it, but it will still lack of touch support to move the panel by swiping the finger over the display, or is it possible? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at [iscroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) library. IMDB's mobile site [m.imdb.com](http://m.imdb.com) does something similar to what you want to do, using iscroll.